# Moving kafka log to another broker

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

Is it possible to move the log on a kafka broker to a different broker?

I'm using kafka as an eventstore (as suggested on their site) so i don't erase the log ever and i am wondering if it is possible to move the log to another broker if my broker fills up (as i expand the cluster).

Also, when a new broker is added and partitions are assigned to it if i understand correctly the old data from the moved partitions stays on it's original broker - meaning if a new consumer is added who wants to consume from the beginning he might not get the events in the correct order - i could solve this if the log was movable.

I know partitions are movable, but if i understood correctly the old data is not moved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the `log.index.size.max.bytes` value from the `Broker Config`? You might have a look at [Broker Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) (consider changing the `log.segment.bytes` & `log.retention.size` as well).

I'm not sure of whether you'll be able to move a log file from one broker to another. But why do you have to do that, since log files are to refer what's going on.

Check all the `log` related configuration properties [over here](http://kafka.apache.org/07/configuration.html).